# gTTS в питон не работает

Tags: python

установил библиотеку все прошло пишу `from gtts import gTTS`
gTTS и gtts подчёркивает красным
помогите пожауйста

Comment: А код-то запускается?

Comment: нет подчёркивает и пишет что не нашел библеотеку